# Talend open studio embeded DB (H2 or Derby)

Tags: h2, derby, talend

I need to use an embedded DB (H2, Apache Derby) with talend open studio. I saw that it's possible with talend MDM, but couldn't find any tutorial on how to embed this in talend open studio.

I have a big amount of data, from different tables that are processed the first time, stored locally before a second step of transformations. But can't use cache memory or files (csv) as middle storage.

Any ideas ? help please

Comment: You can use tJDBC... components to read and write data to/from database without specific connectors

Comment: I have to process a large amount of data, i have to steps of transformation, and between both, i need to store data in DB. I am not the one how uses the job, so i can't ask them to install anything on the server :(, this is why i want the db to be embedded in the job, no install or configuration by final user.
Thanks

Comment: Open source studio doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Talend MDM uses an internal Database for the purpose of the product (data repository). Talend Open Studio (DI) does not use it (there are no internal informations needed with Talend Open Studio for Data Integration).

If you want to connect and extract data from your DB2 database, you can use DB2 components inside your talend jobs.

Comment: Thanks Corentin,
To be more specific, i have data from a JSOn file, there are 2 phases of transformations, between both, i want to store data in an intermediate DB like Derby. but it's not possible to use it as server DB (jobs are used by different team, so i avoid asking them to install anything but run the job).
I am looking for something like derby.jar to store with libraries for example and connect to it when needed.
You think this could be possible ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry I don't see how you can do this without accessing an instance of a DB on a server (or temporary files/cache). Talend produces only an executable job, and doesn't embed a DB with the job.